# How to exclude part of string using regex and change add this part and the and of string?

Tags: regex, string, text

I've got a little problem with regex.

I got few strings in one file looking like this:

```
TEST.SYSCOP01.D%%ODATE
TEST.SYSCOP02.D%%ODATE
TEST.SYSCOP03.D%%ODATE
...
```

What I need is to define correct regex and change those string name for:

```
TEST.D%%ODATE.SYSCOP.#01
TEST.D%%ODATE.SYSCOP.#02 
TEST.D%%ODATE.SYSCOP.#03
```

Actually, I got my regex:

`r".SYSCOP[0-9]{2}.D%%ODATE"` - for finding this in file

But how should look like the changing regex? I need to have the numbers from a string at the and of new string name.

`.D%%ODATE.SYSCOP.#` - this is just string, no regex and It didn't work

Any idea?

Comment: Try searching for `r'(\.SYSCOP)([0-9]{2})(\.D%%ODATE)'` and replace with `r'\3\1.#\2'` (or if it is not Python, `$3$1.#$2`)

Comment: Oh I forget about option with create the groups ! Thanks

Comment: What is the environment BTW?

Comment: Python for support Mainframe

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use [capturing groups](https://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html) with [backreferences](https://www.regular-expressions.info/replacebackref.html) in the replacement part:

```
s = re.sub(r'(\.SYSCOP)([0-9]{2})(\.D%%ODATE)', r'\3\1.#\2', s)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/j4wzbC/1)

Each `\X` in the replacement pattern refers to the Nth parentheses in the pattern, thus, you may rearrange the match value as per your needs.

Note that `.` must be escaped to match a literal dot.

Please mind the raw string literal, the `r` prefix before the string literals helps you avoid excessive backslashes. `'\3\1.#\2'` is not the same as `r'\3\1.#\2'`, you may `print` the string literals and see for yourself. In short, inside raw string literals, string escape sequences like `\a`, `\f`, `\n` or `\r` are not recognized, and the backslash is treated as a literal backslash, just the one that is used to build *regex* escape sequences (note that `r'\n'` and `'\n'` both match a newline since the first one is a regex escape sequence matching a newline and the second is a literal LF symbol.)

Answer (score 1):

- Find: `(SYSCOP)(\d+)\.(D%%ODATE)`
- Replace: `$3.$1.#$2` or `\3.\1.#\2` for Python

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/4I57Rb/1)